# .Net 5.0 - Odata v8.0.2 - /odata/$metadata not working as expected in ubuntu 20.04 with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, odata, ubuntu-20.04, asp.net5

I'm new odata user.

When i use docker-compose to debug with visual studio in windows environment. /odata/$metadata is working well

[image]

But when i deploy my project to ubuntu 20.04LTS server. /odata/$metadata not working as expected. It return same data with /odata

My docker-compose:

[image]

Result when i use wget command to request to /odata/$metadata

[image]

And when i use nginx as proxy to bypass project. It same issue.

What did i do wrong here and what can i do to fix this issue?

You can try:

https://odata.megiservices.com/configurations/odata/$medatada
and
https://odata.megiservices.com/configurations/odata

I use aspnet 5.0 and odata v8.0.2

Thanks for your support.

Comment: I resolved this issue.

Comment: Would you please share more to help use who might have the similar problem.

Comment: Yes, i added \ before $ variable in url.